# Parsing/validating CAS registry number identifiers

Tags: string-manipulation, chemistry

*Mathematica* includes a lot of curated information on molecular structure and properties available through `ChemicalData` and `ElementData`, most of which are nicely indexed by CAS registry number. These numbers are sequentially assigned identifiers that follow some rules and uniquely identify chemicals discussed in the literature. Within `ChemicalData` the CASRN's are strings beginning with "CAS" followed by the standard CASRN format with dashes separating the distinct sections of the identifier.

Does *Mathematica* include any functionality to parse or validate CASRN input? Also, are there any other functions or curated data that utilize CASRN's?

An older package by Jan Mangaldan is [listed in the archive](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/4446/) but doesn't seem to be available, and the link listed there to the validation info is broken.

Comment: Are you not able to download the package from that site?  `ValidCASNumberQ` seems to work

Comment: "but doesn't seem to be available" - I was able to download it fine. Anyway: `Function[l, VectorQ[l, IntegerQ] && TrueQ[Mod[Reverse[Most[l]].Range[Length[l] - 1], 10] == Last[l]]] @ StringCases[ChemicalData["Sildenafil", "CASNumber"], x : DigitCharacter :> FromDigits[x]]`

Comment: I get a page with "file could not be loaded".

Comment: Anyway: is the snippet I gave sufficient for your needs, or are you expecting the CAS numbers to be in a different format?

Comment: Just for reference, the link provided in that package to the check digit calculation method is broken; here is a currently working one, found by searching for "check digit" on the CAS website: https://www.cas.org/content/chemical-substances/checkdig

Comment: @J.M. I wanted something robust to different formats, i.e. "CAS139755-83-2", "139755-83-2", "139755832", are valid "CAS139755-83-1" is not.

Comment: The snippet works on all those strings. The package function also provided support for naked integers like `139755832`, but if all you're expecting are strings, then we're clear.

Comment: @dionys Since you want to cover many formats, you may also want to consider input as an integer (no separators) instead of as a string. Some (perhaps outdated) databases store it in that format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To further simplify the old code and make it fully robust (since among other things `VectorQ[{}, NumberQ]` returns `True`):

```
ValidCASNumberQ[n_String] :=
     With[{l = StringCases[n, x : DigitCharacter :> FromDigits[x]]},
          4 < Length[l] <= 10 && Mod[Reverse[Most[l]].Range[Length[l] - 1], 10] == Last[l]]
```

`StringCases[]` guarantees that only a list of integers or an empty list will be stored in `l`. From there, a CAS number must have a minimum of 5 digits (as noted [here](https://www.cas.org/content/chemical-substances/checkdig)); if that check is passed, only then do we do a checksum calculation.

Here is the corresponding check if we assume the CAS numbers are stored as integers:

```
ValidCASNumberQ[n_Integer] := With[{d = IntegerDigits[n]}, 
     4 < Length[d] <= 10 && Mod[Reverse[Most[d]].Range[Length[d] - 1], 10] == Last[d]]
```

Comment: The specification says "CAS Registry Number® includes up to 10 digits" ... maybe add one more condition to preemptively exclude numbers longer than this limit?

Comment: Yep, added. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
casQ[CASRN_] /; MatchQ[CASRN, _String | _Integer]:=
 Module[{digits, count},
   digits = If[IntegerQ@CASRN, IntegerDigits[CASRN],
                               StringCases[CASRN, x : DigitCharacter :> FromDigits[x]]];
   count = Length@digits;
   count > 4 && count < 11 && Last@digits == Mod[Reverse@Drop[digits, -1].Range[count - 1], 10]
   ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly modified version of the function from the linked package

```
ValidCASNumberQ[n_Integer] := Block[
  {d = IntegerDigits[n]},
  Mod[Most[d].Range[Length[d] - 1, 1, -1], 10] == Last[d]]

ValidCASNumberQ[n_String] :=
 Block[{
   l = StringCases[StringDelete[n, "CAS"], 
     x : DigitCharacter :> FromDigits[x]],
   },
  If[! VectorQ[l, NumberQ],
   False,
   Mod[Most[l].Range[Length[l] - 1, 1, -1], 10] == Last[l]]]
ValidCASNumberQ[n_] := False
```

To modify it, I simply replaced `Characters[n]` with `Characters[StringDelete[n, "CAS"]]` in the string version, to account for different formats of the string (just the number or the form returned by `ChemicalData[entity, "CASNumber"]`). I also updated it based on suggestions from J.M.

Here it is tested,

```
ValidCASNumberQ /@ {"CAS139755-83-2", "139755-83-2", 
  "139755832", "CAS139755-83-1", 98986}
(* {True, True, True, False, True} *)
```

Comment: Jason, could you comment on what you modified and why?

Comment: `Drop[l, -1]` can now be done as `Most[l]`, of course. `Last[IntegerDigits[n]]` can be expressed as `Mod[n, 10]`. The use of `ToExpression[]` can be avoided: `l = StringCases[n, x : DigitCharacter :> FromDigits[x]]`.

Comment: @MarcoB - great point, done!

Comment: @J.M. - also a great point - I didn't really read the function very closely to see how it could be updated